# Python scipy.curve_fit does not fit log-log plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit some experimental data with `scipy.curve_fit` but the fit does not work quite well in a log-log scaled plot. I think the problem is the algorithm which does/doesn`t weight smaller values correctly. Can anybody help me with this please?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(Pe_a,a,b):
    return (0.5 * (1 + special.erf(np.log(Pe_a/a)/(2**(0.5)*np.log(b)))))

Pe_a = np.array([1.372322,1.789089,2.315748,5.588003,6.026619,11.165474,24.438136])
si = np.array([5.494556e-04,4.509410e-04,7.419857e-04,2.360942e-02,3.246023e-02,1.213780e-01,5.173072e-01])

popt,pcov = curve_fit(log_norm,Pe_a,si,p0=[np.mean(Pe_a),np.std(Pe_a)],bounds=(1*10**(-10),np.inf))
```

The correct parameters for the fit should be around `a_opt = 24.17` and `b_opt = 2.2` but instead I get `a = 23.813` and `b = 1.955`. The data fit a standard plot well (small values are close to zero) but for the log-log I get large deviations for smaller Pe_a values. This affects further calculations much.

Thanks in advance

Pyro

Comment: Consider taking the log of both x and y, performing the fit on an appropriately adjusted model, and inverting the transformation

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that you do not have enough data to constrain the optimisation process. Providing the algorithm with uncertainties on your data could be a way forward. For example, have a look at the script below. By decreasing the weight of the second highest value relative to the rest, SciPy yields a fit closer to your expected one.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import erf


def func(Pe_a, a, b):
    return (1 + erf(np.log(Pe_a / a) / b)) / 2


Pe_a = np.array([1.372322, 1.789089, 2.315748, 5.588003, 6.026619,
                 11.165474, 24.438136])
si = np.array([5.494556e-04, 4.509410e-04, 7.419857e-04, 2.360942e-02,
               3.246023e-02, 1.213780e-01, 5.173072e-01])

x = np.linspace(1, 25, 241)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, Pe_a, si)
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label='First fit')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, Pe_a, si, sigma=(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1))
plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), label='Second fit')

plt.plot(x, func(x, 24.17, np.sqrt(2) * np.log(2.2)), label='Expected fit')

plt.scatter(Pe_a, si, label='Data')

plt.legend()

plt.gca().set_yscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me. But now I have the problem finding the "bad points" for giving them weights. This is not the same data point at any simulation.

Comment: Do you have any way to estimate the variance?

Comment: Yes, I could estimate some statistical values like variance but than the "borders" (low and high values) of Pe_a will be weighted with high uncertainties... Problem there is, that it would destroy my further calculations because this si value is kind of interpolation between a minimum and maximum estimation of final result. Meaning if the fit is bad at high and low Pe_a, than the interpolation with si is bad there too.